Workaround for Overfit Model in glmer()
I am analyzing how variable Y increases with variable X with a random intercept based on Z. Currently, I have this model fit:
m1 <- glmer(Y ~ scale(X) + (1 | Z), 
            data = d, family = Gamma(link = "log"))

However, I would like to see how the slope of the model prediction varyies with W -- a categorical variable essentially representing area where the data came from. I tried fitting a similar model using the following code and encountered similar problems with singularity:
m1 <- glmer(Y ~ scale(X) + (1  + scale(X) | W) + (1 | Z), 
            data = d, family = Gamma(link = "log")) #singular fit 

m2 <- glmer(Y ~ scale(X) + (1  + scale(X) | W),
            data = d, family = Gamma(link = "log")) #singular fit 

m3 <- glmer(Y ~ scale(X) + (scale(X) | W), 
            data = d, family = Gamma(link = "log")) #singular fit 

m4 <- glmer(Y ~ scale(X) + (0  + scale(X) | W),
            data = modern_parks, family = Gamma(link = "log")) #singular fit 

I understand that it's a data issue -- there's usually ~5-10 data points that can be used for each group W which is what's causing the problem. However, based on my prior knowledge, variation in the slope of the relationship across W may provide important insights about the relationship overall. I'd like to still explore how this varies but don't have the data to do so using this method. Any recommendations for working around this problem where it would still be meaningful?
Apologies if I formatted this incorrectly, I'm still getting used to conventions on the site. I appreciate any advice anyone has!
Edit: I've continued to work on this and have found that m1 performs better in AIC comparisons compared to simpler models (e.g., random effects for W only, random effects for W and Z, random effects for Z only): all are outperformed by the random slopes for W. This makes sense with what I know about the system I'm modeling, but I want to be sure that I'm assessing it in a statistically appropriate way without overfitting. Thanks!

A few suggestions:

if you're not committed to a log-link Gamma you might try a log-Normal (i.e. lmer(log(Y) ~ ...), which generally gives similar answers to the Gamma and might be slightly better behaved (no guarantees though)
you can use blme::glmer() with a regularizing prior, which will move the model away from the singular 'edge'. In particular, although Chung et al (2013) mostly discuss regularizing priors for scalar random effects (e.g. Gamma priors on variances), they also say:


Our idea can also be applied to models with varying intercepts and slopes where the problem is to regularize the covariance matrix, say Σ, away from its boundary, |Σ|=0. In this case, the log-gamma penalty can be naturally extended to the log-Wishart penalty on Σ, which is equivalent to the sum of log-gamma penalties on the eigenvalues of Σ 1/2.

In particular, using bglmer() will automatically use these regularizing priors (with a slightly stronger shape parameter of 2.5 (scalar)/(2.5 + d) (multivariate), compared to the Chung et al. shape parameter of 2 / 2+d; see help("bmerDist-class", package = "blme") for more info.

You can go all the way to a 'real' Bayesian solution (e.g. MCMCglmm, rstanarm, or brms) with priors, if you prefer ...


Chung, Yeojin, Sophia Rabe-Hesketh, Vincent Dorie, Andrew Gelman, and Jingchen Liu. “A Nondegenerate Penalized Likelihood Estimator for Variance Parameters in Multilevel Models.” Psychometrika 78, no. 4 (March 12, 2013): 685–709. https://doi.org/10.1007/s11336-013-9328-2.
